# httphandler return into string variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, httphandler

I have an httphandler that returns a string (a part description).

I'd like to use the return value in a `title` attribute on an image, which will be updated on a page load.

I have the following code in page_load event...

```
imgThumbnail.Attributes.Add("title", "~/Views/Admin/ImageRepository/ShowDescription.ashx?partno=123456&view=thumb");
```

I'm not sure how to get the `title` text to be the return value instead of just `"~/Views/Admin/ImageRepository/ShowDescription.ashx?partno=123456&view=thumb"`.

How can I do this? This is the first time using an http handler. I have tested the handler and it does return the string I expect it to.

Comment: A handler doesn't seem like the right solution for this - you're going to have to initiate a complete request to the handler at wherever it's registered, as part of the user's current request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to rethink how you are approaching this, your code might look like this:

```
string imgTitle = "Image Title"; // you need to set the value of imgTitle here.
imgThumbnail.Attributes.Add("title", imgTitle);
```

This might give an output like this:

```
<img title="Image Title" />
```

You probably don't want a handler for this, essentially, you could move the code from your handler to your page.

```
string imgTitle = GetImageTitle(partno); // you need to set the value of imgTitle here.
imgThumbnail.Attributes.Add("title", imgTitle);

public string GetImageTitle(string partno)
{
   // put code to return image title here;
}
```

PS are you sure you don't want the `alt` attribute, `<img>` doesn't have a `title` attribute.

Comment: thanks, I do want the title attribute as I am using the jqueryui tooltip. I'll re-consider how I'm grabbing the description. The descriptions are all stored in a database along with an image of the product. I am using a similar handler to return the image of the product and thought I could do the same with the description.